# prism - IsNavigationTarget not invoked when using RequestNavigate

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-4

I am trying to learn the Prism Navigation support. Presently, I have a prism Region and I want to load view to that region using RegionManager.RequestNavigate(). The navigation does occur, however the IsNavigationTarget() of INavigationAware is not invoked, even if the ViewModel of the Navigation Target view implements INavigationAware interface. Here is the code that I am using.

Shell:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <TextBlock Text="Main Window"/>
    <Button Content="RegionA" Command="{Binding NavigateToACommand}" />
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
</StackPanel>
```

ShellViewModel:

```
private void NavigateToA () {
    Uri uri = new Uri("RegionAView", UriKind.Relative);
    RegionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", uri);
}
```

RegionAView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NavigationExample.RegionAView"
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="This is Region A"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

RegionAViewModel

```
public class RegionAViewModel : INavigationAware{

    public RegionAViewModel() {
    }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext) {
        return false; //Not Invoked
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext) {
        //Gets Invoked
    }
}
```

RegionAView.xaml.cs

```
[Export("RegionAView")]
public partial class RegionAView : UserControl {
    public RegionAView() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Why does the IsNavigationTarget() not getting invoked prior to completion of Navigation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you export your view as singleton. modify VM and V as follow:

```
[Export("RegionAView")] 
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public partial class RegionAView : UserControl 
{     
public RegionAView() 
{         
InitializeComponent();     
} 
}
```

Basically, `IsNavigationTarget` will be invoked when you have existing instances. But it will not work for newly created instance.

Comment: katit, I think you are correct. The IsNavigationTarget() gets invoked if there is already a view instance that exists. For the first time, the OnNavigatedTo() is invoked directly without the call for IsNavigationTargert(). So how do we cancel the Navigation if we want to, the first time ? Thanks a lot.